# Creating one jar file from maven modules

Tags: maven

I have Spring Boot project with two maven modules inside main project, every module and main project has its own pom file. When using mvn install I'm getting a two jar files in target folders. So how do I change pom to create only one single jar from application?

```
<modules>
       <module>module_1</module>
       <module>module_2</module>
</modules>
```

Comment: For each module, you get a jar. If you want less jars, use less modules.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Apache Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)

Configure project's plugin (documentation: [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) ).

Configure its descriptor (documentation: [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/multimodule/module-source-inclusion-simple.html) ) For example:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
  <id>src</id>
  <formats>
    <format>dir</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
      <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
      <includes>
        <include>${groupId}module_1</include>
      </includes>
      <sources>
        <includeModuleDirectory>false</includeModuleDirectory>
        <fileSets>
          <fileSet>
            <outputDirectory>sources/${module.artifactId}</outputDirectory>
          </fileSet>
        </fileSets>
      </sources>
    </moduleSet>
  </moduleSets>
</assembly>
```

and run `mvn clean assembly:single` goal to build the assembly.
It packs all classes in a single target jar file.

Answer (score 0):

In case of multi module spring boot application, you will get a jar file in target folder of each module. In case of parent, you will get a fat jar file which will contain all the all the respective jar files from each module. Look into the following pom.xml file about the structure.

https://github.com/debjava/restful-basic-security/blob/master/pom.xml

If you are not using multi module spring boot application, you can use Maven shade plugin to create a fat jar. You can check the following link.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/